# Convert nested Array of Objects into Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to convert this array of objects into an array of arrays. I just want to get the value from "value" key and remove the value from "id" key.

And this is my response data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "f2e77e46-814b-4d73-83db-cb57c341d28f",
        "value": [
            {
                "id": "ba50429d-564a-404c-ba48-e70b9a3971d9",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "d9b49f4a-f184-4dc5-9469-1ad52e23d2dc",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "e1cf76aa-6516-4ed9-bdf7-c4d0d8f07102",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "baacce8d-192c-4353-bef9-9140c611f1d7",
        "value": [
            {
                "id": "b3bf9a68-4abf-43b2-9e3c-2cad0536a7f1",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "7dbe6bad-1a81-45e1-b683-95a185b53f35",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "c5282246-cc18-4ffa-bb57-459df6ae28b9",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1e622287-915d-450b-8ed0-53b4a434030f",
        "value": [
            {
                "id": "2c69caf6-9277-4fcd-9d12-0d0823eb2805",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "9a665798-1318-4662-9a17-abbc6ee77df7",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "786157e5-45e3-4886-8307-f613ab8fcad0",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is what i want it from my response data

```
[
[1,1,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,1]
]
```

I've tried using array map function but this is hard for me and always fail to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `value` property of the individual items and use a nested `map` to extract the `value` property of the `value` array:

```js
const data=[{id:"f2e77e46-814b-4d73-83db-cb57c341d28f",value:[{id:"ba50429d-564a-404c-ba48-e70b9a3971d9",value:1},{id:"d9b49f4a-f184-4dc5-9469-1ad52e23d2dc",value:1},{id:"e1cf76aa-6516-4ed9-bdf7-c4d0d8f07102",value:1}]},{id:"baacce8d-192c-4353-bef9-9140c611f1d7",value:[{id:"b3bf9a68-4abf-43b2-9e3c-2cad0536a7f1",value:1},{id:"7dbe6bad-1a81-45e1-b683-95a185b53f35",value:1},{id:"c5282246-cc18-4ffa-bb57-459df6ae28b9",value:1}]},{id:"1e622287-915d-450b-8ed0-53b4a434030f",value:[{id:"2c69caf6-9277-4fcd-9d12-0d0823eb2805",value:1},{id:"9a665798-1318-4662-9a17-abbc6ee77df7",value:1},{id:"786157e5-45e3-4886-8307-f613ab8fcad0",value:1}]}];

const result = data.map(e => e.value.map(f => f.value));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Change this part `e => e = e.value.map(f => f.value)` to `e=>e.value.map(f => f.value))` I think it is a typo.

Comment: I don't quite understand if there is nested array map function. I think this is the basic that i missed

Comment: @MMuqiitFaturrahman The nested `map` is needed to extract the `value` property from the individual objects in the `value` property of the items in the `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects that contains a `value` array which *also* contains objects. So you need to `map` over the array of objects, and *also* `map` over the `value` array in those object to return the value of each `value` property.

```js
const arr=[{id:"f2e77e46-814b-4d73-83db-cb57c341d28f",value:[{id:"ba50429d-564a-404c-ba48-e70b9a3971d9",value:1},{id:"d9b49f4a-f184-4dc5-9469-1ad52e23d2dc",value:1},{id:"e1cf76aa-6516-4ed9-bdf7-c4d0d8f07102",value:1}]},{id:"baacce8d-192c-4353-bef9-9140c611f1d7",value:[{id:"b3bf9a68-4abf-43b2-9e3c-2cad0536a7f1",value:1},{id:"7dbe6bad-1a81-45e1-b683-95a185b53f35",value:1},{id:"c5282246-cc18-4ffa-bb57-459df6ae28b9",value:1}]},{id:"1e622287-915d-450b-8ed0-53b4a434030f",value:[{id:"2c69caf6-9277-4fcd-9d12-0d0823eb2805",value:1},{id:"9a665798-1318-4662-9a17-abbc6ee77df7",value:1},{id:"786157e5-45e3-4886-8307-f613ab8fcad0",value:1}]}];

const out = arr.map(obj => {
  return obj.value.map(arr => arr.value);
});

console.log(out);
```